# Azure active directory - When adding a new application from the gallery, it doesnt show 'Manage Manifest' option

Tags: saml-2.0, azure-active-directory

We are using Azure AD as identity provider for our SAML SSO enabled application. If we add a new application to azure directory from gallery option, it doesn't show me 'Manage manifest' option. While we add a new app by selecting 'Add an appplication my organization is developing' it shows that option in the bottom.

As a result, we unable to set logout url for application and when we perform a logout for that application, it doesn't redirect back to out service provider application.

Thanks,
Mitesh J.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, applications added by selecting '*Add an application my organization is developing*' and applications added by selecting '*Add an application from the gallery*' have several differences including the ability to edit the manifest, which is only present in the former.

However, you can still set up redirect URIs for both. As you noted, in '*application my organization is developing*', you can do that by editing the manifest or via the Configure page.

For '*application from the gallery*', you can set up a redirect URI by:

1. Select the application in the Azure AD page of the classic Azure Management portal.
2. Click on **Configure single sign-on**
3. Select **Microsoft Azure AD Single Sign-On**
4. In the *Configure App Settings*, check the **Show advanced settings (optional)** checkbox.
5. Set the **Reply URL (optional)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

We already set that value. But i think it is an ACS(assertion consumer service) url which is used to redirect back to SP when there is a login request. For logout request, we doesn't have any option to set return url. 

For other IDPs like Okta, OneLogin, they provide separate option to set logout return url.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to set the logout uri for applications added from the Gallery.